# How I manage the common reference data in Corda

Tags: corda

Wondering what will be a good way to manage common reference data used by all nodes / specified nodes in Corda? One of the example will be a Contract Type or Legal Entity Name, which are the common reference data, shared by specified nodes.

I was thinking Oracle can be the solution, but after the study, seems Oracle is not be appropriate as we only need to get the list of reference data and can be quite frequent.

Other solution I have in mind is to have a centralized place to manage such data and can be obtained thru API. Appreciate anyone can help on this. Thanks.

Kwan

Comment: With "common reference data" do you mean common files / specifications / utilities or something like a State that is shared among all nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Reference data should generally be included in the form of attachments.

The theory is [here](https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-transactions.html#attachments), and you can read about how they work [here](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-attachments.html).